# TYPO3 recursive query for sub-folders

Tags: sql, database, recursion, content-management-system, typo3

I am currently developing a TYPO3 extension where the editors can create datasets within folders. The output of the datasets within one folder works flawless:

```
SELECT * FROM tx_chiliproducts_domain_model_product 
 WHERE hidden=0 AND deleted=0 
   AND pid='.$folderId.' 
ORDER BY sorting ASC
```

But I also want to be able to search through sub-folders recursively.

Example:

```
 windows 
    wood windows
       modern wood windows
       classic wood windows
    plastic windows
```

If I select "modern wood windows" in my plugin, the output shows the corresponding products. But I also want to be able to select "windows" and show every item that is arranged in one of the folders below.

What would such a SQL query have to look like?

Answer (score 0):

In any case, it is strongly encouraged to the API for submitting your query, either extbase or, if it has to be, the old system, pibase.

In pibase, you can use [pi_getPidList($pid_list, $recursive)](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_plugin_1_1_abstract_plugin.html#a5b3eef38e5e11589983b9d79a01d92dc) to get the recursive list of pids and then pass it to your exec_SELECTquery()

(...or, if you absolutely need to - but you really shouldn't - build your SELECT query with WHERE pid IN ($pid_list))

For extbase, I found [this workaround](http://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/198113/), maybe there is something newer already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use Extbase but it seems to be simpler to just add an additional database field to assign categories instead of working with the folder structure in the backend. Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: Well ... from an orthodox standpoint ... "seems" seems to be the right word here :-)